# Is there a test in R whose null hypothesis is that there is a difference between the means of two populations?

Tags: r

I want to conduct a statistical test that will allow me to say that two populations are similar rather than different. As statisticians know, I can't do this with tests like the T test because the null hypothesis of the test is that the populations' means are equal. Hence my question.

Comment: This should either b be flagged and sent to stat.stackexchange.com or just close. There's no programming content here.

Comment: You might search for tests of *bioequivalence*. For some of these tests, I think that the null hypothesis is of a difference between two drugs, with the alternative that the two are the same. This isn't my area of expertise, though.

Comment: Kino, could you please clarify what you mean by populations to be "similar"?  Otherwise you leave the interpretation of this question to the reader, most of whom might not read your mind correctly.

Comment: To clarify, bioequivalence is not limited to biology or medical problems. It is a way of phrasing a null hypothesis where the parameter is less than some value or greater than some value. The alternative is to be inside the bounds. So think of the ball staying outside the goal versus going in as the alternative. (Pick you sport-soccer, hockey, American football, etc.) Usually these 'goal posts' are symmetric around 0, e.g. (-20,20) but adjustments can be made. For example in drug potency studies, it is a typical to want two drugs to have a ratio of potency of 80% and 125%. The log of the ratio

Comment: Given a normal null hypothesis that the means aren't different, doesn't rejection of the null answer this question? Isn't this just a swap around of the null and alternative (2-tailed) hypotheses?

Comment: If you exactly specify how the populations are different, e.g. $H_{0}: \mu_{2} = \mu_{1} + 2$, you could accomplish this with a simple modification of the $t$-test. I don't know how you could derive a test statistic where the null hypothesis is as general as $H_{0} : \mu_{1} \neq \mu_{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If similarity is actually 'bioequivalence', as Georgette explains the concept, then the easiest approach is probably via sampling:

**Sampling solution**

The most obvious approach is Bayesian but I can imagine that bootstrapping will work fine too. For this, define a and b to be the bounds for bio equivalence, sample from the posterior of the difference (or bootstrap a distribution for this difference) and compute the proportion of samples that are less than a or greater than b, and draw your conclusions from this proportion accordingly.  In a Bayesian interpretation, this proportion is the probability that the samples are not actually equivalent, which you can threshold any way you like to make a decision.

(If you're very confident about distributional assumptions then you could use the sampling distribution of the equivalent parameter in a regression model and do the whole thing without sampling via one application of *lm* and *vcov*, and two of *qnorm*.)

**On Testing**

The approach above is more an estimation / modeling approach than a testing approach.  That's deliberate because I think this makes more sense for your problem.  Separate issues arise if you really want to *test*.  By this I mean: do you really want the inside/outside judgement distinction to be asymmetric in the way that specifying a null hypothesis in the Fisherian sense would make it?  My bet is that you don't.

In passing, I would stay well away from 'Bayesian testing' when it involves point hypotheses or their negations.  Sensible priors are hard to find and tend to affect the results, which is just the model's way of saying that the probability that a parameter/difference is exactly x is (both mathematically, and in real life) zero.  That said there may be other approaches that avoid this kind of 'problem' and these problems need not necessarily affect some operationalisation of the bioequivalence problem.

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian statistics allow you to quantify support for the null-hypothesis, which in this case is that two means are equal. After computing a regular $t$-value you can compute the Bayes factor using, among other methods, this web page:

http://pcl.missouri.edu/bayesfactor

Comment: I think this might be a little misleading. (mean 1)=(mean 2) is a point null hypothesis, which in the Bayesian framework always has probability zero (??) (I'll have to go read the link you posted, but I have my doubts.)  I would instead direct the OP to @whuber's comment above ...

Comment: Here are a few references: http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2009/WetzelsEtAl2009Ttest.pdf, http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2010/WagenmakersEtAlCogPsy2010.pdf